# Is the following derivation of predicate logic correct?

Tags: logic, proof, predicate-logic

[image: Question]

I recently discovered https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/, except I'm still figuring out the appropriate rules that are needed for the system to check my proof. I thought it'd be quicker to turn to humans.

Comment: What is step 4?

Comment: A different approach can be: assume the negation of the antecedent of the 2nd premise and derive a contradiction with 1st premise.

Comment: The second premise should be written like this:  (¬∃x (¬Gx ∧ Fx)) → Hac.  The way it's written it looks like the whole implication is within the scope of the existential quantifier, which is not what you meant.  Other than that what you wrote looks ok.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "?X" is supposed to be an indefinite subgoal, according to my professor. It's a line that always follows right after the line that states, e.g., ~A, if I want to prove A by indirect proof (IP).

Comment: @causative I've indeed been wondering about the proper use of parenthesis when it comes to quantifier. But if the whole implication goes within the quantifier, wouldn't the expression be written as: ¬∃x ((¬Gx ∧ Fx) → Hac)? (I do agree that your (¬∃x (¬Gx ∧ Fx)) → Hac makes the expression much clearer, though.)

Comment: Forallx has serious conceptual errors, and I strongly recommend against it. An alternative that seems fine is "Language, Proof and Logic", as mentioned in [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684208/21820). Another alternative that I prefer is [my system](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820) (also linked from the other post), but there is a limit to how much I can say in a single SE post. If you have any questions about LPL's or my system, feel free to ask me in [this chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics).

Comment: @user21820 thanks, I'll check these out 